# display all item refere by nodeaccess_userreference module

Tags: drupal, view, reference

i use http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference for refer node user to user.
users can see title of node in the box in my account but display all node i want expire node in boxes in my account users or
how to create views and show title of node with filter by user reference and expire in special time

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Uph... you need to be more clear.

Regarding the expiry, you can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and regarding the view I was not able to get your requirement.